# Angular CRUD Modal

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a CRUD application, and it also has a modal box for searching patients, from the same component page. So now my issue is that my modal removes the **ID** from the component after selecting a patient and closing the modal and the error says **undefined**. So now I want to know how can I make the modal not to remove my ID and not write **undefined**?

**Below is the CRUD I have created:-**

[image]

**Below is the modal search:-**
[image]

Code:- create-patient-register.component.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
 import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
 import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
 import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

 //model data
 import { Patient } from './../../../shared/patient/patient.model';
 import { InpatientRegister } from './../../../shared/inpatient-management/inpatient-register/inpatient-register.model';

 //service
 import { InpatientRegisterService } from './../../../shared/inpatient-management/inpatient-register/inpatient-register.service';
 import { PatientService } from './../../../shared/patient/patient.service';

  @Component({
  selector: 'app-create-patient-register',
  templateUrl: './create-patient-register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-patient-register.component.css']
  })
  export class CreatePatientRegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  patientList: Observable<Patient[]>;
  filter = new FormControl('')

  @ViewChild('autoShownModal') public autoShownModal: ModalDirective;
  public isModalShown: boolean = false;

  public showModal() {       
  this.isModalShown = true;        
   }

  public hideModal() {
  this.autoShownModal.hide();
  }

  public onHidden() {
  this.isModalShown = false;
  }

  
  inpatients: InpatientRegister[];
  patients: Patient[];

  constructor(public service: InpatientRegisterService, public patientservice: PatientService) { 

}

   ngOnInit(): void {
   this.patientservice.getPatientList().then(res => this.patients = res as Patient[]); 
  } 

   populateForm(selectedRecord: InpatientRegister) {
   this.service.formData = Object.assign({}, selectedRecord);
   }
```

**Code:- create-patient-register-component.html**

```
      <!-- button click for modal searching -->
     <button (click)="showModal()">Search Patient</button>

      <!-- modal starts here -->
    <div *ngIf="isModalShown" [config]="{ show: true }" (onHidden)="onHidden()" bsModal 
     #autoShownModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Patient Search</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="hideModal()">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
                <div class="form-group form-inline">
                    Full text search: <input class="form-control ml-2" type="text" [formControl]="filter"/>
              
                </div>
              </form>
              <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">#</th>
                  <th scope="col">Fisrtname</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let patient of patientList | async; index as i">
                  <th scope="row">{{ i + 1 }}</th>
                  <td (click)="populateForm(patient)"  (click)="hideModal()">
                    <ngb-highlight [result]="patient.firstname" [term]="filter.value">{{patient.firstname}}</ngb-highlight>
                  </td>
                
                </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
      </div><!-- model ends here -->

      <!-- form parent starts here-->
      <form novalidate autocomplete="off" #form="ngForm" (submit)="onSubmit(form)">
              <label>ID</label>
            <input type="text" name="inpatient_id" [value]="service.formData.inpatient_id" />

<div class="form-group">
    <label>NAME</label>
    <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Full Name" name="firstname"
        #firstname="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.firstname"
        required [class.invalid]="firstname.invalid && firstname.touched">
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid">SUBMIT</button>
</div>
         </form>
      <!-- form parent ends here-->
```

**I am using this example here:-** https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/stackblitzes/modal/basic/stackblitz.html - But now it returns defined.

Comment: can u make a minimal reproduce? too hard to read all of your code

Comment: @naoval I just did. Please let me know when you still want me to reproduce.

Comment: can i take alook at that?

Comment: @naoval I am using this example here: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=app/modal-basic.ts - But now it returns undefined.

Comment: i think u gave the wrong url

Comment: sorry please try this one: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/stackblitzes/modal/basic/stackblitz.html

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5tbden try this

Comment: Cmiiw, you trying to get Patient detail when u click them then add that value to parent form, am i right?

Comment: @naoval Yes, you are correct and it works but now my issue is the first 'ID' that changes to 'undefined' after clicking a patient.

Comment: and you did that using `populateForm` ? may i know how that function looks like

Comment: @naoval I have updated and added the populateForm and you can find it under ngOnInit()

Comment: ah youre using object.assign, i haven't tried using that i always using `patchValue` to assign each value to the `formControlName` or `ngModel`

Comment: if you log `selectedRecord` how it looks like?